# htaccess not redirecting to custom 404 page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a custom 404 page called 404page.php  , and I have the htaccess file with the line that I found should work (this is the only line I have in the .htaccess file)

`ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php`

It was working fine yesterday, but today I was optimizing images and some other stuff on the website, and when I reuploaded it, the htaccess didn't redirect to 404page.php anymore, but to a page that has this written:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /asfsdtg was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

(I just typed asfsdtg to test if it was working).

The website is uploaded online and I'm managing it through cpanel (I'm still a beginner). I searched for some solutions, I tried adding another line to .htaccess, then it looked like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php
```

I even tried putting the location of the 404page.php as a local link, and the internet link, and it still gave me the weird error page.

Does anyone have some idea whats happening? If you need more info that I didn't supply please tell me what more I can supply

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663899/htaccess-errordocument-404-redirect-not-working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397868/custom-404-error-issues-with-apache

Comment: Try this 

Redirect 301 /404 /404page.php

Comment: @PardeepPathania should that be the only line in the .htaccess? if yes its still the same

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404page.php [L]

set the path of 404page.php in place of /404page.php in last line

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try out this:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404   http://yoursitename.com/404page.php
```

And be sure that `404page.php` exists on the root of your server and is trully called `404page.php` not `404Page.php`

Be carefull at the characters, this is key sensitive!

Comment: Also try to disconnect from the server and reconnect again to try this steps!
Is recomended to use filezilla or other ftp client to edit files on your server!

Comment: oh my god... i took a closer look at the file names, and the htacces file was named "htaccess", and NOT ".htaccess"... I'm ashamed, sorry guys, thanks for your time

Comment: ErrorDocument is part of core, not mod_rewrite, so the `RewriteEngine on` directive doesn't do anything in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Try with like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404   http://www.sitename.com/404.php
```

Comment: it's still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

## Make to handle any 404 errors.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php
```

If above setting does not works you have to write addition line of code as mentions below.
Which identifies for  non existing files and directories and redirect to 404.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```